# scheduler endTime not working

Tags: kendo-ui

I can't make the Scheduler to work correctly when setting endTime
[EndTime Documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/scheduler#configuration-endTime)
Events are shown even after the endTime date:

```
<script>
    $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
        date: new Date("2013/6/6"),
        startTime: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00"),
        endTime: new Date("2013/6/8 18:00"),
        //views: ["day", "week"],
    views: [{
        type: "day",
        startTime: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00"),
        endTime: new Date("2013/6/6 18:00")
    }, {
        type: "week",
        startTime: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00"),
        endTime: new Date("2013/6/6 18:00")
    }, ],
    dataSource: [
      {
          id: 1,
          start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
          end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
          title: "Interview",
          //"recurrenceRule": "FREQ=DAILY", "recurrenceException": "",
      },
      {
          id: 2,
          start: new Date("2013/6/10 08:00 AM"),
          end: new Date("2013/6/10 09:00 AM"),
          title: "Interview",
          //"recurrenceRule": "FREQ=DAILY", "recurrenceException": "",
      }
    ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `endTime` option controls the end time display in day and week views. Only the time portion is taken under consideration. You can try the `min` and `max` options:

```
min: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00"),
max: new Date("2013/6/8 18:00")
```

Comment: Shouldn't it limit user input - i.e. no events can be added after the endTime?

Comment: No, it doesn't do that.

Comment: Hi @AtanasKorchev, what about the timeline views ?